# python remove all duplicates include that elements

Tags: python

```
input: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6]

output: 4
```

Tried, set, form new list, but cant figure out how to get rid of all duplicates including the element itself.

Comment: Is the input list already sorted?

Comment: It will be good if you'll [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of answers which you find best.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
filtered_list = [value for value in my_list if my_list.count(value) == 1]
print(filtered_list)
[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, using collections.Counter

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inp = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6]
>>> counted_inp = Counter(inp)
>>> counted_inp
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 4: 1})
>>> [inp_item for inp_item, inp_count in counted_inp.items() if inp_count == 1]
[4]
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
inp = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6]
res = list(filter(lambda x: inp.count(x) == 1, inp))  # list() isn't necessary for python 2
```